# Configuring Cisco client to auto reconnect

Tags: cisco, vpn

I found this that shows how to do what I want: https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/24851/how-configure-vpn-client-automatic-vpn-initiation

Can someone tell me what am I supposed to put for the Network property? Not sure what IP this represents.

Comment: Links get broken over time. You need to edit your question to quote the relevant portions of the linked document, too. Also, what do you mean by "_the Network property_"?

Comment: Reading the linked document, these are instructions configuring an end-device, like a PC. This would be off-topic here. You should try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Network property in a section of the auto-initiation list defines a subnet on which the client must be for auto initiation to be triggered.  What you put there depends on your network's configuration.  In the example provided by Cisco, a client with an IP address in 110.110.110.0/24 would be classified under the [ChicagoWLAN] section.

You should note that the link you provided refers to software no longer available from or supported by Cisco.  The IPsec VPN Client reached end of life on July 29, 2014.